# Why am I unable to import my component in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I am doing a basic import of a component and it keeps on giving me this error:

```
./src/Nav.js
Module not found: You attempted to import ..\node_modules\@pmmmwh\react-refresh-webpack-plugin\lib\runtime\RefreshUtils.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
```

But my Nav component is inside the /src.

my import

```
  import React from 'react'
    
        const Nav = () =>  {
        
            return(
                <header class="header">
                    
                </header>
            )
        }
        
        export default Nav
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-timesheet-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.16",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "webpack": "^5.22.0"
  }
}
```

I recently had a similar problem with missing packages, if that is the reason for the error, why do I keep on getting them?

Comment: The error you are getting about the react-refresh-webpack-plugin module and not your Nav component. Did you run an npm install in your project?

Comment: I installed some packages like babel and helmet and that's it. Should I just write npm install in terminal?

Comment: Please show your package.json file

Comment: You get this error because this component is not located in your node_modules directory. Check your package.json file in the root dir of your project to see exactly what modules you have in your project. If you have modules there that are not installed you will get this kind of errors.

Comment: Added package.json . Any idea why don't I have modules installed when I made the project with npx create-react-app my-app?

Comment: somewhere in your code you are importing react-refresh-webpack-plugin, however you have not installed it. Simply write `npm i --save react-refresh-webpack-plugin`

Comment: or remove the import if you aren't using that library